# Removing a half-blank line and precisely calculating a space

Tags: spacing, indentation, enumerate, enumitem

Consider the following MWE:

```
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text,
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a line \mbox{\parbox[t][][t]{\textwidth-\widthof{MMMx This is a line}}{

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textit{(\roman{enumii})}]
\item  Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 
\item Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 
\end{enumerate}

}}\end{enumerate}
```

I have to questions:

1) I would like that "(i) Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1" be display on the same line as "This is a line". How can I do that ?

2) I would like the spacing  between the last word of  "This is a line", i.e. "line", and the first word of "(i) Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1", i.e. "Text" be a normal space. Because "This is a line" is already indented I tried to account for this indentation by adding "MMMx" as additional spacing in `\widthof`. But this is just eye-measure. How can I make this precise ?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it contains a complete example code (from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`). Without this it may be difficult for anyone to help you. I have no idea where the `\widthof` macro comes from.

Comment: Please make your example into a complete document and so can run it and see, You are using various contributed packages (enumitem I would guess but you don't say) so it is very hard to guess what alignment you are seeing. (_all_ questions should have a complete example document)

Comment: Sorry. `\widthof` is in the `calc` package (I assumed this was widely used, so there wasn't a need to mention the package explicitly); since I used the tag "enumitem" in my question I implicitly assumed that this package also had to be added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to guess; use `minipage` instead of `\parbox` and remove the `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\begin{document}
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text,
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a line
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-\labelwidth-\labelsep-\widthof{This is a line}}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\textit{\roman*})]
  \item Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
  \item Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A better definition that allows for nesting at every level; but keep in mind that nesting several enumerations is bad style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for showing the page margins
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}

\newenvironment{xenumerate}[1]
 {\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\widthof{#1}}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\textit{\roman*})]}
 {\end{enumerate}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text,
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a line 
  \begin{xenumerate}{This is a line}
  \item Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
  \item Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
  \end{xenumerate}
\item Text text text text text text
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Text Text Text Text
    \begin{xenumerate}{Text Text Text Text}
    \item Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
    \item Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
    \end{xenumerate}
  \item End of the story
  \end{enumerate}  
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version with an optional argument for changing the label

The default label is `label=(\textit{\roman*})` as before, but you can change it as you please.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}

\newenvironment{xenumerate}[2][label=(\textit{\roman*})]
 {\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\widthof{#2}}
  \begin{enumerate}[#1]}
 {\end{enumerate}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text,
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a line 
  \begin{xenumerate}{This is a line}
  \item Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
  \item Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
  \end{xenumerate}
\item Text text text text text text
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Text Text Text Text
    \begin{xenumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]{Text Text Text Text}
    \item Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
    \item Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
    \end{xenumerate}
  \item End of the story
  \end{enumerate}  
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Two question though: Why doesn't removing `\labelwidth` and `\labelsep`  change the spacing ? I noticed, that you're using `\roman*`. What is the difference to `(\roman{enumii})` and where can I find more info on using the "`*`" on this command ?

Comment: @user10324 Removing `\labelwidth` and `\labelsep` would make the box too wide and stick in the right margin. `\roman*` is an `enumitem` trick: it allows to refer to the counter pertaining to the current level of the list, so you don't need to know it's `enumii`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, another day another piece of knowledge :) (I was so busy looking at the distance between "line" and "(i)" that I didn't even notice the line sticking in the right margin :)

Comment: I just observed that the text does stick out in the right margin, if I use your code, but nest it more deeply, i.e. the "This is a line" is already a nested entry. What could I do in this case to have text aligned at the margin ?

Comment: The part “1. This is a line” is indented because you are in an `enumerate` environment. If you want “1.” to be flush to the left margin, say `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]` for the outer one.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I posted a picture, to explain more clearly, what the problem is:http://tbf.me/a/CQjrCV

Comment: @user10324 Now it should satify your needs. I'll put it in my gallery of typesetting horrors, though. `;-)`

Comment: This is great! Would upvote multiple times if I could! Do you perhaps also know if it is possible to make the style of the label a parameter of the `xenumitem` environment, i.e. that I can give `xenumitem` the `(\textit{\roman*})` as a parameter for its label ? I'm going to use this a couple of times with different labels and it'd be more elegant, if I wouldn't have to define for each new use a new type of `xenumitem` with a different label style.

Comment: @user10324 I'll add it in a moment.