# enumerate in itemize environment, no new line

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to have something looking like this:

```
\item  
\item 1.  
      2
```

My intention is to have the first enumerated item in the same line as the itemize item. I read something about \leavemode, but it doesn't work for me. (The enumeration should be aligend)

Minimal example:

```
\begin{itemize}  
\item1      
\item2 blabla \leavemode \begin{enumerate} \itema   
          \itemb   \end{enumerate}  
\item3    
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you looking for an inline list? Can you provide a minimal example where you can show what you would like to achieve and what goes wrong in your current solution?

Comment: In a standard `article` document `\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}` produces what you ask.

Comment: Does this question help? [Removing a half blank line and precisely calculating a space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176246/)

Answer (score 7):

A solution comes from the `enumitem` package: the first item is introduced through the `enumerate*` environment (inline enumerate); it is declared to be the first element of a *to be continued*  series — a notion introduced by enumitem in version 3.0. The other items come from an enumerate environment, belonging to the `tobecont` series, with suitable values of `\topsep` and `\partopsep`.

Here is an example, in which I afford the luxury of two inline items first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fourier} 

\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
    \item Blahblah

    \item Blahblah 
        \begin{enumerate*}[series = tobecont, itemjoin = \quad]
        \item a \item b
        \end{enumerate*}

         \begin{enumerate}[resume = tobecont, ,topsep = 0pt, partopsep = 0pt]
        \item c
        \item d
        \end{enumerate}

\item Blahblah
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to forego page breaks in the sublist and don't mind specifying the width, then you can use a `minipage`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2 blabla
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate} \item a
    \item b \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}

\item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is still a line break after item 2, item a is not in line with item 2

Comment: In the example above they are on the same line and the output matches what you indicated in the question.