# How do I reproduce the numbered items in a Beamer list in text?

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, itemize

I wrote a theorem in beamer with \enumerate.
Then I need to write "Idea of proof of 1", with "1" which should be written the same way it appears in the theorem, ie a blue dot with a 1 inside. Also "1" must be written next to "Idea of proof of" and not at the head.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{example}
\author[...]{...}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definizione}{Definizione}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theoremmm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{theoremmm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{theoremmm}

Idea of proof of 1

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What written here ([enumerate in itemize environment, no new line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176885/enumerate-in-itemize-environment-no-new-line)) solves my problem in LaTex, but the proposed solutions use \ enumitem, which does not work in Beamer.

Comment: HI and welcome. Please give a MWE : [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: I hope I did it well

Comment: Your code is not compilable. I got these error `LaTeX Error: File "beamerthemePisa.sty" not found.` Where did you find this Pisa theme ?

Comment: Sorry, I have changed it

Comment: Does this question solve your problem? [Getting the theme's itemize bullet in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269309/138900)

Comment: I read it, but I can't put the "1" into the ball

Comment: +1 It's a real question ! Change the title of your question so that it is easy to understand and indexed by a search engine. For example, *"How do I reproduce the numbered items in a Beamer list in text?"*

Comment: @TobiBS This question is not duplicated, you are mistaken. Please retract your closing request.

Comment: @TobiBS Click again on close, you can withdraw.

Comment: @TobiBS Never mind, if it's closed, we can open it again.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}` to show item label, for numbering the template use `enumi` counter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{example}
\author[...]{...}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definizione}{Definizione}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theoremmm}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\itemnum}[1]{%
\setcounter{enumi}{#1}\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}% 
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{theoremmm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{theoremmm}

Idea of proof of \itemnum{1} ...


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Very nice solution !

Answer (score 2):

The enumerate bullet is defined in the beamer source code in the file `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`. You can copy the code from there and use it in a new command, where you supply an argument instead of the enumerate counter. The commands are listed as `\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{ball}` for the sphere, `\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{circle}` for the circle, and `\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{square}` for the square template.

For the circle template there is an additional font setting (with a `\usebeamerfont` command). You need to add a group (a pair of `{}` within the command) to prevent the font setting from taking effect outside of the command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% sphere shape
\newcommand{\enumbullet}[1]{%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor{item projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{1.75}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
      \pgftext{%
        \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
        \color{fg}#1}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

% circle shape
\newcommand{\enumcircle}[1]{%
  {\usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{0ex}{1ex}{2ex}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.2ex}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    \pgftext[base]{\color{fg}#1}
  \end{pgfpicture}}%
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{example}
\author[...]{...}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definizione}{Definizione}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theoremmm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theoremmm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{theoremmm}

Idea of proof of \enumbullet{1} and \enumbullet{2}

\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\begin{frame}
\begin{theoremmm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{theoremmm}

Idea of proof of \enumcircle{1} and \enumcircle{2}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Very nice answer! Can you add the exact name of the command you are using in your answer?

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I had to draw a circle with a "1" inside instead of a sphere with a "1" inside?

Comment: @user222167 that is defined in the same template file, see edit.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why is "and" on the last line written in blue and not black?

Comment: @user222167 I didn't see that, but Teepeemm was right, an extra group prevents the font setting from having effects outside of the command.