# Referring to colored bullet points in Beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, bullets

When I put enumerate inside an itemize environment on Beamer, I get little blue bullet points with white numbers inside.

But when I try to refer to them, it just appears as the number. How do I reproduce the blue bullet point with the white number inside?

Here's the code:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Enumerated things}
\begin{itemize}
\item We have two enumerated things:
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{item:r<g} enumerated thing 1
\item\label{item:more_zeroes} enumerated thing 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Trying to refer}
\begin{itemize}
\item We we refer to it, it just says ``\ref{item:r<g}''. But I want to produce the blue circle with the number inside it.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the circle just by using `\ref{item}` (which would be difficult) or would something like `\mycircle{\ref{item}}` be ok (somewhat easier)?

Comment: That could work, but then how can I make it a blue circle and a white number? I want it to clearly refer to what appeared on the previous slide.

Comment: In that case it's a duplicate I think.

Comment: I'd like to point to the following excellent answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558288/88262

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick hack:
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\circled}[1]{%
  \scalebox{0.6}{\tikz\node%
    [outer sep=0pt, inner sep=2pt,
      line width=0pt,text=white,fill=blue!50,draw,circle,shading=ball]{#1};%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\bref}[1]{\circled{\ref{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Enumerated things}
\begin{itemize}
\item We have two enumerated things:
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{item:r<g} enumerated thing 1
\item\label{item:more_zeroes} enumerated thing 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
Try to refer:
\begin{itemize}
\item When we refer to it, it just says ``\ref{item:r<g}''. But I want
  to produce the blue circle with the number inside it.
\item Try \bref{item:r<g} and \bref{item:more_zeroes}.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is indeed similar to the approach in the duplicate. However, I would advise against calling the new command `\cref`, because this name is already in use by the popular `cleveref` package. Something like `\circleref` or `\enumref` would be better.

Comment: Also the shade of blue is not fully the same color as in the original enumerate list.

Comment: @Marijn, you are absolutely right. I saw your comment under the question after posting my quick hack.